# SQL : select rows with value in some column and the value does is not contained in another table

Tags: sql

There are two tables

**Students**:

```
ID | Name | Age
---+------+-----
1  | Alex | 19
2  | Matt | 23
3  | Ali  | 19
```

**Actions**:

```
ACTIONID | Description
---------+---------------------------
1        | Alex hasn't paid yet
```

I want to select Student ID with age 19. But don't want to select student whose name is contained in any row of description column from the `Actions` table.

So result should be the following

```
ID: 3
```

How to do that? Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT student.ID 
FROM Students student
WHERE 0 = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM Actions action 
           WHERE action.Description LIKE CONCAT('%', student.Name, '%')
AND student.Age = 19;
```

Comment: Thanks. It's conrrect

Comment: You can also use the EXISTS method instead of '0 = (SELECT(*) ...' method. Get a look on Internet how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question.

```
select ID from Students where Age = 19
```

Comment: You don't understand my question